# Most convenient integer type for processor

Tags: c++, performance, types, cpu-word, promotions

According to what I've heard, **integer values** that are not the processor's **word size** will be **promoted** when modifying them (using +, -, &, etc). The `long` type is supposed to the the word size. On my compiler, `int` is **32-bit** and `long` is **64-bit**.

Does this mean `long` is **more efficient** than `int` despite requiring more memory?

One more thing, do **compound operators** also promote the values? And what about the *increment* and *decrement* operators?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent on this, but I think most common processors nowadays have both 32bit and 64bit operation modes, so if you have two `int32`s, it may end up loading them at the same time (because it can) but using them separately. That is, without a need for promotion. Like I said, I'm not so sure though.

Comment: Compound operators are `+=`, `-=` etc.

Comment: @MarkB I know that. I just wondered if these required promotions as well. Although, that too may depend on the conditions I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter, this isn't something you can control. Choose the narrowest type which is wide enough to represent the values you need. This is the best you can do under any and all circumstances.

The language guarantees the *result* of operations will be correct, and the compiler will choose the most efficient path to that result that it can find. This may involve changing integer sizes at some stage, or may not.

The processor may do its own internal transformations. Again, without changing the result. Again, it's out of your hands.

Comment: I suppose so. I just did some tests to check which is faster and I didn't notice any difference between bool, char, int, long and long long.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be hard for anyone to give you a straight-forward answer. The best you can do in this case is to profile and see for yourself.

But unless you make millions of operations with the numbers, I doubt it will matter which is faster. Write readable code first, profile, and optimize only after.

I also heard that it's faster to have an `if (int)` rather than `if (bool)` because the `bool` would get promoted to `int` (counter-intuitive, I know), but no one declares an `int` instead of a `bool` just for the sake of performance. (unless, maybe, after profiling)

Answer (score 1):

In line of principle, plain `int` should be the "fast, normal use integer", while `long`, when different, can mean "extended range but *may* be slower".

What actually happens depends strongly from the platform you are working on.

On several microcontrollers I used `int` is 16 bit and `long` is 32 bit, and operations on `long` take more than one processor instructions.  On "classic" 32 bit x86, `long` and `int` are usually the same, so there's no difference at all. On x86_64, depending on the portability concerns, `long` may be 32 or 64 bit; as far as "instruction count to perform an operation" they are the same, but the increased size can matter if you have to read/store big arrays of integers in memory (32 bit integers may perform better because more fit in cache) (and probably there are much many considerations you could do, optimization is often counterintuitive, *especially* on x86).

So, long story short: don't overthink this issue, if you need a "normal" integer that is guaranteed to work fast and its range is ok for your application just use `int`. If you need a minimum guaranteed size, look at the `typedef`s of `<stdint.h>` (which, besides giving you exactly-sized integers, provides also "fastest integer with this minimum size").

But as always, the usual rule applies: if you have performance problems first profile, then optimize.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean long is more efficient than int despite requiring more memory?

That depends entirely on your computer. There is no one perfect integer type that is universally optimal. If it's critical to performance you'll need to check with some analysis tool. If it isn't critical to performance you shouldn't care.